# Where does the folder /usr/lib/windows95 come from and how can I get rid of it?

Tags: directory, electron

Trying to free some space on my root partition I stumbled across a folder named

```
/usr/lib/windows95
```

It contains the following files:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 4,2K  blink_image_resources_200_percent.pak
-rw-r--r--   1   18  content_resources_200_percent.pak
-rw-r--r--   1 7,2M  content_shell.pak
-rw-r--r--   1 9,8M  icudtl.dat
-rwxr-xr-x   1 2,8M  libffmpeg.so
-rwxr-xr-x   1  22M  libnode.so
-rw-r--r--   1 1,9M  LICENSES.chromium.html
drwxr-xr-x   2 4,0K  locales
-rw-r--r--   1 171K  natives_blob.bin
drwxr-xr-x   2 4,0K  resources
-rw-r--r--   1 110K  ui_resources_200_percent.pak
-rw-r--r--   1 1,7M  v8_context_snapshot.bin
-rw-r--r--   1   13  version
-rw-r--r--   1  56K  views_resources_200_percent.pak
```

I couldn't determine where this folder belongs to and how can I remove it cleanly. It might have to do something with the electron frame work. Could somebody give me a hint please?

Comment: What is the output of `dpkg -S '/usr/lib/windows95'`?

Comment: It might be from [felixrieseberg/windows95](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows95/)

Comment: It gives `windows95: /usr/lib/windows95`, and this is the solution. I think it was this project I was once interested in: https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows95/releases/tag/v1.3.0 Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: So now you know the package name you can simply remove it using `apt-get`

Comment: I'm going to send it as an answer ... feel free to accept it if you think it was helpful to you ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find out which package this path belongs to, run:

```
dpkg -S /usr/lib/windows95
```

it will returns something similar to:

```
[package-name]: /usr/lib/windows95
```

then use the package name to remove it:

```
sudo apt autoremove [--purge] package-name
```

---

PS: it might be from [felixrieseberg/windows95](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows95/)